# change application language in start activity using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android

i used below code to change language:

```
public void setLocale(String languageToLoad){
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

my problem is when i try to load "locale"  using SharedPreferences  it seem to be trap in a loop because of refreshing activity. so how can i load the last locate in start activity.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the code that calls setLocale?

Comment: Could you compare the locale to set with the locale that is set? If they are the same, do nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //some code here
    if (last_local.equals("fa") && current_local.equals("en"))
        setLocale("fa");
    //some code here
}

 public void setLocale(String languageToLoad){
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    SharedPreferences Settings=getSharedPreferences("Last Setting",1);
    Settings.edit().putString("Locale Status", languageToLoad).commit();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

my problem was in onstop() method that i save the loace and it was cause of loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to launch the activity again. You need just to reinit the views and layout by calling setContentView().